# sh shell: how do I grab and store values, which may have space, in an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, whitespace

I am trying to write a script to grab the users from the `passwd` file

```
USERS_LIST=( $( cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1 ) )
```

the above would do the trick up until now because I only had users with no spaces in their names.

However, this is not the case anymore. I need to be able to resolve usernames that may very well have spaces in their names.

I tried reading line by line the file, but the same problem exists (this is one line but I have indented it for clarity here):

```
tk=($( while read line ; do 
       j=$(echo ${line} | cut -d":" -f1 ) 
       echo "$j" 
       done < /etc/passwd )
   )
```

unfortunately if I try to print the array, the usernames with space will be split in 2 array cells.
So username "named user" , will occupy array [0] and [1] locations.

How can I fix that in `sh` shell?

thank you for your help!

Comment: `sh` has no arrays. Thus, you can't store *anything* in an array in sh.

Comment: ...now, *bash* has arrays, but can we clarify which shell you're targeting?

Comment: BTW, all-uppercase names for internal variables is bad form; all-uppercase names are reserved for builtins and environment variables honored by system tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true about uppercase... this is a veeery old script i had to revisit...

Comment: In ash or dash, by the way, `users_list=( $( cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1 ) )` won't store anything at all, but will fail with `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are bash (and ksh, and zsh) features not present in POSIX sh, so I'm assuming that you mean to ask about bash. You can't store anything in an array in sh, since sh doesn't have arrays.

---

Don't populate an array that way.

```
users_list=( $( cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1 ) )
```

...string-splits and glob-expands contents. Instead:

```
# This requires bash 4.0 or later
mapfile -t users_list < <(cut -d: -f1 </etc/passwd)
```

...or...

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a users_list < <(cut -d: -f1 </etc/passwd)
```

---

Now, if you **really** want POSIX sh compatibility, there *is* one array -- exactly one, the argument list. You can overwrite it if you see fit.

```
set --
cut -d: -f1 </etc/passwd >tempfile
while read -r username; do
  set -- "$@" "$username"
done <tempfile
```

At that point, `"$@"` is an array of usernames.

Comment: can't have `mapfile` in `sh` , or `readarray` for for that matter

Comment: @nass, you can't have arrays at all in `sh`, so your question makes no sense at all there.

Comment: if i start my script with `#~/bin/sh` and this is not a link to `/bin/bash` and then I write the cmd as stated in the question, where am I storing the values I grabbed. because I really can print any other them using indices...

Comment: @nass, how am I supposed to know which shell provides `/bin/sh` on your system?

Comment: there also seems to be some error with the `IFS...` line.... `syntax error near unexpected token <' `

Comment: There is no one canonical `sh` implementation; it could be one of tens of shells; the only thing they promise is to *at least* implement all POSIX sh features; they don't promise to implement no non-POSIX features.

Comment: Yes, that's consistent with using a shell that can't handle `<( )`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75881/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-nass).

Comment: Of *course* it's impossible -- there **does not exist** any solution for arrays in POSIX sh, because POSIX sh does not have arrays.